# How to find source files for things installed via yum on CentOS

Tags: yum, source

I want to see the source files for deamons that I have installed on CentOS via yum.
Can they be found locally or should I just go to the repository site for them.

I know its trivial but I would like to see the exact source that I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get the source rpms `<pkg name>-<version>.src.rpm`. Yum can't do this natively, but if you install the yum utils and add a couple of repos you can grab them easily.

This site [explains](https://web.archive.org/web/20120108164456/http://www.imminentweb.com/technologies/yum-download-source-rpm) the process better than I can off the top of my head :).

Also the quickest and easiest way to get the source out of the RPM is the setup a [build environment](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetupRpmBuildEnvironment) then you just install the source RPM. the source will be in `$BUILD_ROOT/SRC`

Answer (score 1):

CentOS uses rpm packages, binary equivalent to RedHat, so you can use standard RH weapons to access the files in the packages:

`rpm -ql /var/cache/yum/reponame/packages/filename.rpm`

This will query the package (if it is installed) and show you where the files are.

Comment: The wanted rpms where from rpmforge but /var/cache/yum/rpmforge/pachages where empty.
However I was able to find many rpms for the some base rpms. 
Thank you